# Ant task for compiling GUI forms (Intellij IDEA)

Tags: java, user-interface, scala, ant, intellij-idea

How I can create a Ant task to compile GUI forms (XML) in Intellij IDEA? I use Scala and Java in my project. Java only for GUI class, and I create it with Intellij IDEA UI Designer.

Comment: How would you do it from a CMD.exe window?

Comment: I don't use windows, but I don't know.

Answer (score 9):

Please don't beat me, but after setting the 'Generate Ant Build'-dialog like:

[image]

the errors are gone:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting/sharing this! Was trying to figure out why my ${idea.home} property was not being set, and showing as an error in the generated ant build script file.  Amazing how much grief a single checkbox can cause.

Answer (score 5):

IDEA provides a Ant task, javac2, that does this.  It's a drop-in replacement for the standard javac Ant task.

First, you'll need to include something like the following near the top of your Ant build file.

```
<path id="javac2.class.path">
    <pathelement location="${idea.dir}/redist/forms_rt.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${idea.dir}/redist/javac2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${idea.dir}/redist/annotations.jar"/>
</path>
<taskdef name="javac2" classname="com.intellij.ant.Javac2" classpathref="javac2.class.path"/>
```

Here "${idea.dir}" refers to the directory of your IDEA installation.  Those jars are redistributable, so you can copy them into your project if you wish, and refer to them there.  Once you've done that, just replace any calls to "javac" tasks with "javac2", and everything should just work.

To compile scala, of course, you'll need calls to either scalac or fsc, but those are unaffected by all of this.

Comment: Ant show me: "/My/project/path/build.xml:16: taskdef class com.intellij.ant.Javac2 cannot be found", why?

Comment: I change "redist" by "lib" and then Ant don't show me these error.
Now, Ant show me this error: /My/project/path/build.xml:16: taskdef A class needed by class com.intellij.ant.Javac2 cannot be found: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor

Comment: Hmm, looks like you need to add

  <pathelement location="${idea.dir}/lib/asm.jar"/>

as well.  Not sure why you jars are in lib rather than redist.  Community Edition, possibly?

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here.
Solved this way:

```
<property  name="idea.lib" value="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 9.0.3\\lib"/>

<path id="javac2.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${idea.lib}/javac2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${idea.lib}/jdom.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${idea.lib}/asm.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${idea.lib}/asm-commons.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${idea.lib}/jgoodies-forms.jar"/>
</path>
<taskdef name="javac2" classname="com.intellij.ant.Javac2" classpathref="javac2.classpath"/>
```

Comment: In my compile.classpath I also had to add this: <fileset dir="${idea.dir}">
    <include name="lib/forms_rt.jar" />
</fileset>

Answer (score 2):

Since this comes up on google, here is what is needed:

```
<property name="javac2.home" value="${idea.home}/lib"/>
<path id="javac2.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${javac2.home}/asm.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${javac2.home}/asm-all.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${javac2.home}/javac2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${javac2.home}/jdom.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${javac2.home}/asm-commons.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${javac2.home}/jgoodies-forms.jar"/>
</path>
```

The key is asm and asm-all which solves ClassReader and ClassWriter errors. I had to look in the jars to find that out. "javac2.home" will be OS dependent. This is on Intellij Ultimate.

Comment: Thanks for this. For me, I had to look into the actual /lib folder. In my version of IDEA the asm JARs had version numbers in the file names which had to be added here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct way:

```
<property  name="javac2.home" value="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\\lib"/>
<path id="javac2.classpath">
      <pathelement location="${javac2.home}/asm.jar"/>
      <pathelement location="${javac2.home}/asm-all.jar"/>
      <pathelement location="${javac2.home}/javac2.jar"/>
      <pathelement location="${javac2.home}/jdom.jar"/>
      <pathelement location="${javac2.home}/asm-commons.jar"/>
      <pathelement location="${javac2.home}/jgoodies-forms.jar"/>
 </path>
```

Works for both Intellij Community and Ultimate. Tested in both. Just change it to your Intellij Community path, so "IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.1.4", for example.

Comment: Actually, look at Martin Pfeffer's answer below for a better/non-hardcoded way of setting the 'javac2.home' property.  While your approach does work, have the IDE do it for you seems like a better route to go.