# Using IntelliJ Javac2 compiler instead of standard compiler in Gradle

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a project that contains IntelliJ forms and need to compile it with the javac2 compiler. This used to be done as an Ant task as described here: [Ant task for compiling GUI forms (Intellij IDEA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434555/ant-task-for-compiling-gui-forms-intellij-idea)

Is there a way how to replace the standard java compiler with the javac2 compiler in Gradle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421826/set-jdk-home-javac-path-in-users-gradle-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I could do in Gradle. The Java classes are first compiled and then instrumented by javac2:

```
configurations {
    intellij
}

dependencies {
    intellij 'com.intellij:javac2:13'
}

compileJava {
    doLast() {
        project.ant.taskdef name: 'javac2', classname: 'com.intellij.ant.Javac2', classpath: project.configurations.intellij.asPath
        project.ant.javac2 srcdir: project.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.join(':'),
                includes: 'yourpackage/**/*.form',
                classpath: project.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.asPath,
                destdir: project.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,
                source: project.sourceCompatibility,
                target: project.targetCompatibility,
                includeAntRuntime: false,
                instrumentnotnull: project.ext.instrument
    }
}
```

Comment: Which repository are you downloading `com.intellij:javac2:13` from? It doesn't look like recent versions [are in Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intellij/javac2).

Comment: @Thunderforge Must have been something in the company's local cache. No idea and can't check anymore ;)

Comment: That seems to be the situation we are in. We are migrating company repositories and our old one had it in cache, but we can't find a public repo where the new one can get it from. Perhaps it was removed at some point.